# Fill area between 2 curves matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

If i have 3 vectors: mean, mean+standard deviation and mean-standard deviation, how can I fill the space between mean+standard deviation and mean-standard deviation and keep visible the third vetor "mean"?
I tried like this

```
h1 = area(x,y_m);
h2= area(x,y_std1);
h3= area(x,y_std2);
```

but it fills the entire space under mean+standard deviation.
In that code, y_m=mean; y_std1=mean+standard deviation; y_std2=mean-standard deviation. These vectors are imported from excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this may provide what you are looking

```
% random data
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = sin(x);
ystd = ones(size(x))*1;
y_std1 = y+ystd;
y_std2 = y-ystd;

figure
fill([x fliplr(x)],[(y_std1) fliplr(y_std2)],'r'); hold on
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: I found something like that but I can't understand what it does. In my case, x goes between 0 and 50; while y has a lot of values. I already have deviation standard; I don't think I need to recalculate that.

Comment: okay, so x, y, ystd are your own data. The above example was to generate something to plot. 
I assume that your x-values are sorted. Let me make an explanatory example:
    x = [1 2 3 4];
    y1 = [1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4];
    y2 = [0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6];
    [x fliplr(x)]     = [1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1];
    [y1 fliplr(y2)] = [1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9];

fliplr reverses the order, 
fill is used to paint a closed shape, the above example generates a closed shape

Comment: @Shika93 You need to use `fill` because it lets you fill a shape defined by x and y coordinates. `area` will fill all of the space from a given baseline which is not what you want. The first argument of `fill` takes x-coordinates, the second the y-coordinates. To draw a closed shape you need the x-coordinates twice. Once to go from left to right and then again from right to left (where they are reversed with `fliplr`). The y-coordinates are `y_std1` from L to R and `y_std2` from R to L (again they are reversed from R to L). These coordinates define the boundaries of the shape that `fill` draws