# fill function in Matlab 2017 does not work

Tags: matlab, fill

I was trying to fill the area between a horizontal line and a curve. I am following the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865798/fill-area-between-2-curves-matlab). The 2 curves are

[image]

The code I am using to generate the graph is

```
alpha = [0:0.01:1];
mu = 1;
V = [0:0.01:10];
Lambda1 = 2;
y2 = (1./(mu-alpha*Lambda1)+2*alpha*Lambda1./((mu-alpha*Lambda1).^2)).*(alpha<=0.3)+max(V).*(alpha>0.3);
f0 = max(V).*ones(1,length(alpha));
A = [alpha,fliplr(alpha)];
Y1 = [f0,fliplr(y2)];     
figure
h1 = fill(A,Y1,'k'),axis([0 1 0 11]),
set(h1, 'FaceAlpha', 0.1)
```

The idea is that `alpha` is the running variable, i.e., the horizontal axis. The blue curve is a piecewise function, i.e., before `alpha=0.3`, it is a qudratic function, and after `alpha=0.3`, it stays at 10. Basically, I want to have the region when `0<=alpha<=0.3` be shaded.

I thought my above code would work, since I thought I understand how the `fill` function works. The `x,y` in `fill(x,y,'r')` are 2 vectors representing the coordinates of the boundary of a share in 2D space.

I don't know why in my case it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. But your function has a singularity for `alpha=0.5`: `(mu-0.5*Lambda1)=0`.

So your `y2(51)=NaN` and Matlab -rightfully- screws up.

Comment: thank you so much! I didn't realize that originally. I know the first part of my `y2` will have the singularity at `alpha=0.5`. But I thought it should not be a problem as I have an indictor function `(alpha<=0.3)`. Now apparently matlab does not do the computation as I thought. I learn it now.